# Flask+nginx+uwsgi: only serve url with nginx if flask doesn't have a route for it

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

nginx config for the server (the main nginx one is the default one on debian 9):

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
    location /galleries {
        autoindex on;
        alias /srv/galleries/;
    }
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/scraper.sock;
    }
}
```

uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /tmp/scraper.sock
chmod-socket = 777
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
plugins = python3
py-autoreload = 1
```

If I try creating a route for /galleries/whatever, ie like this:

```
@app.route("/galleries/whatever")
def test():
    return "Hello"
```

I'll just see the indexed files inside /galleries/whatever through nginx instead of going through flask.

Is there a way for me to force nginx to only handle requests if flask returns 404? Alternatively, is there a better way for me to serve files while still having them available under those urls? Keep in mind the /galleries folder is pretty big and generated by another program.

I run the server with "uwsgi --ini server.ini" and nothing else.

Comment: Maybe using a subdomain name is an idea to overcome this problem?

Comment: You mean using a subdomain specifically for the files, having the rest of the path be identical to flask's routes? That's an option, but I was hoping on some simpler solution - I'd like to make my app portable rather than relying on configuring subdomains every time.